# Erro System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

Estou com erros no `Titular.Text` deste form e não sei como resolver.

```
public partial class Titular : Form
    {
        private Conta[] contas;
        private int quantidadeDeContas;
        public Titular()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Titular_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.contas = new ContaCorrente[30]; 

            this.contas[0] = new ContaCorrente();
            contas[0].Numero = 1; contas[0].Nome = "Conta Corrente";
            contas[0].Titular = new Cliente();
            contas[0].Titular.Nome = "Vitor";
            contas[0].Saldo = 100;

            contas[1] = new ContaPoupanca();
            contas[1].Numero = 2;
            contas[1].Titular = new Cliente();
            contas[1].Titular.Nome = "Mario"; contas[1].Nome = "Conta Poupanca";
            this.quantidadeDeContas =30;
            foreach (Conta conta in contas)
            {
                if (conta != null)
                    comboContas.Items.Add(conta.Titular.Nome);
            }
            comboContas.DisplayMember = "Titular";
        }

        private void comboContas_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string titularSelecionado = comboContas.Text; 

            int indiceSelecionado = comboContas.SelectedIndex;
            Conta contaSelecionada = contas[indiceSelecionado];
            txtTitular.Text = Convert.ToString(contaSelecionada.Nome);
            txtNumero.Text = Convert.ToString(contaSelecionada.Numero);
            txtSaldo.Text = Convert.ToString(contaSelecionada.Saldo);

        }

        private Conta BuscaContaSelecionada()
        {
            int indiceSelecionado = comboContas.SelectedIndex;
            return this.contas[indiceSelecionado];
        }
        private void btnSaca_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string txtValorSaque = txtValor.Text;
            Conta contaSelecionada = this.BuscaContaSelecionada();

            contaSelecionada.Saca(Convert.ToDouble(txtValor.Text));
        }

        private void btnDeposita_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string txtValorDoDeposito = txtValor.Text;
            Conta contaSelecionada = this.BuscaContaSelecionada();
            contaSelecionada.Deposita(Convert.ToDouble(txtValor.Text));
        }

        private void btnTransferir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Conta conta1 = BuscaContaSelecionada();
            int indiceSelecionado = cmbDestinoDaTransferencia.SelectedIndex;
            Conta conta2 = this.contas[indiceSelecionado];

            conta1.Transfere(Convert.ToDouble(txtValor.Text), conta2);
            txtTitular.Text = conta2.Titular.Nome;
            txtNumero.Text = conta2.Numero.ToString();
            txtSaldo.Text = conta2.Saldo.ToString();
        }

        private void btnClean_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtTitular.Clear();
            txtNumero.Clear();
            txtSaldo.Clear();
            txtValor.Clear();
        }

        private void cmbDestinoDaTransferencia_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int indiceSelecionado = cmbDestinoDaTransferencia.SelectedIndex;
            Conta contaSelecionada = this.contas[indiceSelecionado];

            txtTitular.Text = contaSelecionada.Titular.Nome;
            txtNumero.Text = contaSelecionada.Numero.ToString();
            txtSaldo.Text = contaSelecionada.Saldo.ToString();
        }

        public void AdicionaConta(Conta conta)
        {
           if (quantidadeDeContas == contas.Length)
            {
                Conta[] temporario = new Conta[contas.Length * 2];
                for (int i = 0; i < this.contas.Length; i++)
                {
                    temporario[i] = this.contas[i];
                }
                this.contas = temporario;
            }
            this.contas[this.quantidadeDeContas] = conta;
            this.quantidadeDeContas++;
            comboContas.Items.Add(conta);
        }

        private void btnNovoCadastro_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CadastroDeConta cadastroDeContas = new CadastroDeConta(this);
            if (cadastroDeContas.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK            
            {
                Application.Run(new CadastroDeConta(this));            
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Onde exatamente esta acontecendo o erro?

Comment: Posta o ZIP com o Projeto pra eu abrir aqui? AI podemos ver onde está o erro... Não deve ser algo muito cabuloso não.

Comment: Era importante saber onde está o erro exatamente, em que linha, caso contrário vamos lançar dicas à sorte.

Answer (score 1):

Um [IndexOutOfRangeException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx) exceção é lançada quando um índice inválido é usado para acessar um membro de uma matriz ou uma coleção, ou de leitura ou gravação de um local específico em um `buffer`. Essa exceção herda o `Exception` classe mas adiciona membros não exclusivos.
Normalmente, um `IndexOutOfRangeException` exceção é lançada como resultado de erros de desenvolvedor. Em vez de tratar a exceção, você deve diagnosticar a causa do erro e corrigir seu código.

Provavelmente você esta tentando acessar um index de seus objetos que não existe.
Podendo ser qualquer um desses.

```
int indiceSelecionado = comboContas.SelectedIndex;
Conta contaSelecionada = contas[indiceSelecionado];
```

/

```
private Conta BuscaContaSelecionada()
        {
            int indiceSelecionado = comboContas.SelectedIndex;
            return this.contas[indiceSelecionado];
        }
```

/

```
Conta conta1 = BuscaContaSelecionada();
            int indiceSelecionado = cmbDestinoDaTransferencia.SelectedIndex;
            Conta conta2 = this.contas[indiceSelecionado];
```

/

```
nt indiceSelecionado = cmbDestinoDaTransferencia.SelectedIndex;
            Conta contaSelecionada = this.contas[indiceSelecionado];
```